# In django template, how to compare str with date

Tags: python, django, string, date, templates

In django template, I want to compare 2 values: 1 string with 1 date.

```
my_string = '10:30'
horaire = date
```

My code :

```
{% if my_string == horaire|date:'g:i' %}
   something to do
{% endif %}
```

values are same, but it never match... :(

I forget something?

Comment: Easier to debug if you put this logic in your `views.py`

Comment: whats the `horaire`'s format look like? and are you sure about `date:'g:i'` filtering ?

Comment: `my_string` comes through the context just like `horaire` so instead pass `dates_match` through the context after making that comparison in your view. It's typical & advised to handle your logic in the view as you can debug easier. Also by doing this you cut down the amount of data being passed through the context.